# Split complex string with Regex in JAVA

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I want to Split following strings to an array with Regex in JAVA but I don't know how to do.

```
string1="advmod(likes-4, also-3)"  ==>    advmod, likes, also
string2="nsubj(likes-4, dog24-2)"  ==>    bsubj, likes, dog24
string3="num(dog24-3, 8-2)"        ==>    num, dog24, 8
```

Please help me to do this work? how split the string like *"num(dog24-3, 8-2)"* in three tokens **num**, **dog24** and **8** and then putting they to an string array.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: regex will be unique for every string ..

Comment: ok. how to split these strings with regex. thanks

Comment: @Vaibs_Cool i don't think so... letter or digits unti "(", same until "-"+digits , same until "-"

Comment: Why do you want to do it exactly with regex?? just for  exercise?

Comment: yes. I want to find best regex for string like that(be fast and correct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generic:

```
String string[] = {"advmod(likes-4, also-3)",// ==> advmod , likes , also
        "nsubj(likes-4, dog24-2)",// ==> bsubj , likes , dog24
        "num(dog24-3, 8-2)"};//==> num ,dog24 , 8
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\(([^-]+).*, ([^-]+)");
for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(string[i]);
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.print(i+": ");
        for(int j=1; j<= m.groupCount(); j++){
            System.out.print(m.group(j));
            if(j!=m.groupCount()) {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps, it works for me.

This is the output:

```
0: advmod, likes, also
1: nsubj, likes, dog24
2: num, dog24, 8
```

Answer (score 1):

For 3rd String

```
  String re1="(num)";   // Word 1
    String re2=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re3="(dog24)";   // Alphanum 1
    String re4=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re5="(8)";   // Integer Number 1

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
    if (m.find())
    {
        String word1=m.group(1);
        String alphanum1=m.group(2);
        String int1=m.group(3);
        System.out.print("("+word1.toString()+")"+"("+alphanum1.toString()+")"+"("+int1.toString()+")"+"\n");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.but num, dog24 and 8 are variable and can be change with other words like other string1 and string2.

Comment: Now this code doesn't make Java look like the best option for regex computations...

Answer (score 1):

You if you want to split, you could use this:

```
str.split("\\(|-[0-9]+(?:,\\s+|\\))");
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/UgvSVO).

Answer (score 0):

You really haven't described your grammar, but assuming that it's something like looks like a Java method or a Prolog statement, try

```
final static String TOKEN_CHARACTERS="[\w\d-]"
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(" + TOKEN_CHARACTERS + "+)\((" + TOKEN_CHARACTERS + "+,\s*(" + TOKEN_CHARACTERS + ")\)$";
```

Then split on the `-`; I presume that it really is there for some reason, and it's not clear that it's always present (if so, you can change the pattern to hard-code the single `-` instead of considering it part of the token). If you allow additional space or such, adjust accordingly.